# PostGIS upgrade 1.5->2.1 on OSX

Tags: postgis, postgresql, osx, library

i'm struggling updating my installation of PostgreSQL/PostGIS, from 9.1/1.5 to 9.2/2.1.

I'm on OSX Mountain Lion and using the very useful ports from W. Kyngesburye. I followed the procedure :

- Updated PostGIS 1.5 to 2.0
- Dumped databases
- Updated databases to postgis 2.0
- Installed PostgreSQL 9.2 and PostGIS 2.1

I'm stuck at the step of using pg_upgrade i've got an error saying :

> Could not load library `$libdir/postgis-2.0`
>   ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
>
> Could not load library `$libdir/rtpostgis-2.0`
>   ERROR:  could not access file `$libdir/rtpostgis-2.0`: No such file or directory

Those libraries are in `/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/lib`

pg_config returns that the lib directory is /usr/local/pgsql-9.2/lib

If i switch the symbolic link /usr/local/pgsql to 9.1 again, same problem.

Thanks for your help, i'm very eager to use the new functions of 9.2/2.0 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine at [Gis-Blog.fr](http://www.gis-blog.fr/) found the answer : i had to install PostGIS 2.0 for PostgreSQL 9.2 too.

Luckily, it was available at the "Software archive" page of KyngChaos : http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive